# Custom UITableViewCell XIB repeats row after scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, storyboard, objective-c-blocks

I have one Custom UITableViewCell with xib.

ProductCell

And another viewcontroller with Tableview.

Now i want to add Cell in to tableview.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tblList.dataSource = self;

    [self.tblList registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProductCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierList"];

//other code lines apart from tableview.
}
```

TableView Datasource

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.aryData count];
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100.0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierList"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [self.aryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblProductName.text = [dict objectForKey:@"Product"];

    cell.tag = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"CELL : %@",cell);

    return cell;
}
```

Console Data which you will see that instance are repeated. **(It cause issue with check box of cell and UIstepper value of cell which are subviews of cell).**

```
2014-12-09 18:45:43.619 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d9b804b90; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d994b6330>>
2014-12-09 18:45:43.622 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d99663780; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d99664b90>>
2014-12-09 18:45:43.625 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d996a5870; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d996a56b0>>
2014-12-09 18:45:43.628 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d9b817e50; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d9b817c90>>
2014-12-09 18:45:43.630 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d9b81e810; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d9b81e650>>
2014-12-09 18:45:43.633 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d9b825140; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d9b824fd0>>
2014-12-09 18:45:54.978 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d996a7400; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 80); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 6; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d996b4520>>
2014-12-09 18:45:55.241 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d9b804b90; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 375 100); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; tag = 7; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d994b6330>>
2014-12-09 18:45:56.824 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d99663780; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 100; 375 100); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; tag = 8; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d99664b90>>
2014-12-09 18:45:57.045 RetailCheckOut[4777:132965] CELL : <ProductCell: 0x7f9d996a5870; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 200; 375 100); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; tag = 9; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9d996a56b0>>
```

ProductCell class xib not in Storyboard but its separate.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. `UITableView` re-uses cells for performance reasons. You've actually told it to do this yourself, here:

```
    ProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierList"];
```

Notice **`dequeueReusable`** in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` - this method reuses a cell from your tableView's queue when possible.

I can't see what's going on with your stepper and check box from the code you've posted, but what you probably need to do is set their values in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Additionally, in ProductCell's .m file, you can implement `prepareForReuse` in which you can return the cell to its default state.

Comment: Here Repeating cell means, I have 50 rows, First it display 7 rows, once i start scroll, I got same instance back. So not able to proper set values.  
See this instance : 0x7f9d9b804b90 repeated after 7 rows.

Comment: Yes, and that is what is supposed to happen. Why does this mean you are not able to set the proper values for your Stepper and Checkbox? Do you have outlets for them?

Comment: Yes,I have add UIStepper and UIButton (customise checkbox) in ProductCell outlet.

Comment: Ok, so you should set the correct value/state for them in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Whatever i have did in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, which i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: If i select 1st row checkbox, and scroll 8th number row check automatically selected. This is happening b'coz of instance repeated.

Comment: Yes, so you need to set the state of the checkbox for each `indexPath` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should use the `indexPath` to decide, based on your model, what state the checkbox should be in (on or off). You need to store the states of the user's selections in your model somewhere, so that you can set the cells up appropriately each time.